# Skrollr is very choppy when manipulating background-position

Tags: jquery, frontend, parallax, skrollr

I am using Skrollr and no matter what I do, my images (at a low file size: 16kb) create choppiness when their background position is manipulated on scroll:

```
<section id="slab2" class="vc-container"
    data-bottom-top="background-position: 0px 0px"
    data-top-bottom="background-position: 0px 100px"
>
    <div class="vc-item">
        <p data--300-bottom="color: rgb(53,176,174)"
           data-center="color: rgb(153,224,223)"
           data-960="background-attachment: fixed"
        >
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia quae itaque delectus soluta minima minus maiores, provident sit!"
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any idea what can be wrong? I set smoothScrolling = true, which I hear is default anyway. I have two different jQuery sliders in my code. Not sure if this will mess with the transitions

Comment: I had a problem similar to this a while back - are you using Chrome by any chance? Check to see if it's smoother on other browsers.

Comment: Any chance you're using the `background-size` property?